# How can I programmatically upload JFrog Artifacts to GiLab registry?

Tags: gitlab, artifactory

I have jfrog backup with the below format:

```
./repositories
./repositories/digital
./repositories/digital/admin
./repositories/digital/admin/revealjs-digital-signage
./repositories/digital/admin/revealjs-digital-signage/v1.artifactory-metadata
./repositories/digital/admin/revealjs-digital-signage/v1.artifactory-metadata/artifactory-folder.xml
./repositories/digital/admin/revealjs-digital-signage/_uploads
./repositories/digital/admin/revealjs-digital-signage/v1
./repositories/digital/admin/revealjs-digital-signage/v1/sha256__6b8971be6dd8206db197c075c2078e750466e8c8086a6781363b3b509236b127.artifactory-metadata
./repositories/digital/admin/revealjs-digital-signage/v1/sha256__6b8971be6dd8206db197c075c2078e750466e8c8086a6781363b3b509236b127.artifactory-metadata/properties.xml
./repositories/digital/admin/revealjs-digital-signage/v1/sha256__6b8971be6dd8206db197c075c2078e750466e8c8086a6781363b3b509236b127.artifactory-metadata/artifactory-file.xml
./repositories/digital/admin/revealjs-digital-signage/v1/sha256__c5ec31d8205545276d3ec1e2a8a77308aa52865dda22241b8e32d4e46daaf82a
./repositories/digital/admin/revealjs-digital-signage/v1/sha256__91cedd97621ca699948e
```

I need a way to migrate JFrog Artifacts to GitLab.

Answer (score 0):

You can tell the runner to upload any files or directories you need like this:

```
artifacts:
  paths:
    - ./repositories/
```

The full documentation for the artifact keyword is here: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#artifacts

Comment: I have multiple type of artifacts [ Docker, NPM, Maven, ..etc], that won't work with my case

Comment: It solves the use case in your question though. For NPM, the syntax is the same but the directory would be `node_modules` (and I’m assuming it’s the same with Maven too). Docker is different though, assuming you’re building a docker image. After it’s built you’ll have to push it to docker hub, gitlab’s registry, or a private registry like: `docker login [registry]...; docker push my-image;`